# YouTube wrong on tagged game

Tags: youtube

I made a FPS game and posted a video of it on YouTube. For some reason YouTube is saying that the game in the video is Roblox, even though it is a custom game I made. How can I correct this so that it does not say that the game is Roblox?
(It should not say anything about what the game is.)

It only says this on desktop.

[image: screen shot from desktop version of YouTube]

Link to video: [FPS in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z425sbqGrJ4)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the game title in [YouTube's Video Manager](https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U). Select your video, open 'Details' and click 'Show More'. Set the category to 'Gaming', then search for your game's title and select it on the list. (This will only work for games YouTube recognizes)

[image: Changing game title in video manager]

Comment: what if the game is in development? (and you're the developer)

Comment: @tatsu There doesn't seem to be an option for custom game titles. I'm not sure where YouTube pulls its game list from.

Comment: this is such BS. I had to change the category to Entertainment to get rid of the mis-tag